# Angular/Typescript - get array out of http response with map OR get specific element

Tags: angular, typescript

Q1: How to get an array of objects from a http response with a map?

Q2: And how to get a specific object from a http response with a map?

The example URL, example data, CurrencyAPIResponse and Currency object are given below.

I tried 2 methods and many other options, but they don't work:

Q1: Get an array of objects from a Map property of the Response object:

```
get(): Observable<Currency[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CurrencyAPIResponse>('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .pipe( map( response => Array.from( response.bpi.values())));
}
```

Q2: Get 1 specific Currency object from a Response with a Map property:

```
getOne(name: string): Observable<Currency> {
    // @ts-ignore
    return this.httpClient.get<CurrencyAPIResponse>('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .pipe( map( response => response.bpi.get( name)));
}
```

Using [the specified url](https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json) you get an object containing a map. The data looks like:

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Jun 5, 2022 12:04:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2022-06-05T12:04:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Jun 5, 2022 at 13:04 BST"
  },
  "disclaimer": "Some text",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "29,698.5140",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 29698.514
    },
    "GBP": { ... }, 
    "EUR": { ... }
  }
}
```

My type and object definition is:

Currency:

```
export class Currency {
  code: string = '';
  symbol: string = '';
  rate: number = 0;
  description: string = '';
  rate_float: number = 0;
}
```

The CurrencyAPIResponse:

```
interface CurrencyAPIResponse {
  "time": {
    "updated": string, // or this should be a date? 
    "updatedISO": string,
    "updateduk": string
  },
  "disclaimer": string,
  "chartName": string,
  "bpi": Map<string,Currency>
}
```

Comment: response.bpi.USD.code (or whatever). Json does not support maps, just objects in this case. So get() or value() will not work.

Comment: Ok, tx, how to create the correct Response type?

Comment: Create a type for it, or create a class where you map your response to (which can then contain a Map again if you prefer that - but in general pretty much unneeded). So basically, you’ll loose your server types because of the serialization and deserialization of json. And json only supports a few basic types (string, boolean, number, object, array and undefined). Welcome to frontend development ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get what you want by piping your observables you can do something like this:

```js
get(): Observable<Currency[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CurrencyAPIResponse>('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
  .pipe( 
      pluck('bpi'),
      map(obj => [...Object.values(obj)])
  );
}
```

For the one:

```js
getOne(name: string): Observable<Currency> {
    return this.get()
  .pipe( 
      map(array => array.find(element => element.code === name))
  );
}
```

*I would avoid things like this and just make the first http call once, and then use a function to get out the individual currencies with `array.find(element => element.code === name)`.*

Comment: I wrote this without IDE or testing it, so I hope it compiles. XD

Answer (score 2):

It is not `Angular HttpClient`. It is more `Javascript` related.

For `Q1` you can use multiple choices to convert an `Object literal` into an `Array`. If you are interested in processing the values (create an array of values) you can use `Object.values(putYourObjectHere)`. If you are interested in processing the keys (create an array of keys from your original Object) you can use `Object.keys(putYourObjectHere)` and so on...

For `Q2` you can use `Array.prototype.find()` among other `ES5` and `ES6` options. To read about [find() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Additionally, you can create your own quick dictionary lookup method and use it to lookup particular values as follows: function myCustomLookUp(array, key){return array[key]}